# jquery find fails when argument has invalid characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery. If I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="container" title="Mark">
```

and I run:

```
find('div.container["title=Mark"]');
```

then it works. Which means, the element is found.

However, if I have another div that looks like this:

```
<div class="container" title="Mark Person">
```

then it doesnt work. Which means: the element is not found and jquery give an exception:

```
Error, Syntax Error: unrecognized expression.
```

It seems that when "title" is a string with no whitespaces or other characters like slash, then it works. In other case, jquery doesnt understand that tag.
is there a way to avoid changing in my code everywhere (it is a lot of changes) and make find-function to work with this elements?

Comment: Please have a look at the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) again. It's right there in the heading: "Attribute Equals Selector `[name="value"]`". [I somehow doubt `div.container["title=Mark"]` works](http://jsfiddle.net/n3hno1an/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `"` marks in the wrong place. Place them around the value:

```js
var mp = $(document).find('[title="Mark Person"]');

mp.css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" title="Mark Person">should be bold</div>
<div class="container" title="Mark">should not be bold</div>
```